# r multiple column subtraction

Tags: r, dplyr, subtraction

The reduced version of my dataset is as shown below.

```
 Z_dog1_mu1  Z_dog2_mu1  Z_dog3_mu1  Z_cat1_mu1  Z_cat2_mu1   Z_cat3_mu1                                                
 0.0000      0.0000      0.0001      0.0005      0.0043       0.0045   
 0.0039     -0.0016     -0.0102     -0.0009      0.0421      -0.0139
-0.0380     -0.0733      0.0196      0.0261      0.0628       0.0463
-0.1036      0.0784     -0.0529      0.1053     -0.0511      -0.0138
```

I am trying to substract the dog* columns from the cat* columns like this

```
 df$diff1 <- df$Z_dog1_mu1   -  df$Z_cat1_mu1
 df$diff2 <- df$Z_dog2_mu1   -  df$Z_cat2_mu1
 df$diff3 <- df$Z_dog3_mu1   -  df$Z_cat3_mu1
```

How can I do this more efficiently and faster without manually subtracting each column as shown above. I have around 100 dog columns `(Z_dog1_mu1...Z_dog100_mu1)`  and 100 cat columns`(Z_cat1_mu1...Z_cat100_mu1)` /. Any advise is much appriciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We subset the 'dog' columns, and 'cat' columns separately and then do the subtraction

```
nmdog <- grep("^Z_dog\\d+_mu", names(df))
nmcat <- grep("^Z_cat\\d+_mu", names(df))
df[paste0("diff", seq_along(nmdog))] <- df[nmdog] - df[nmcat]
df
#  Z_dog1_mu1 Z_dog2_mu1 Z_dog3_mu1 Z_cat1_mu1 Z_cat2_mu1 Z_cat3_mu1   diff1   diff2   diff3
#1     0.0000     0.0000     0.0001     0.0005     0.0043     0.0045 -0.0005 -0.0043 -0.0044
#2     0.0039    -0.0016    -0.0102    -0.0009     0.0421    -0.0139  0.0048 -0.0437  0.0037
#3    -0.0380    -0.0733     0.0196     0.0261     0.0628     0.0463 -0.0641 -0.1361 -0.0267
#4    -0.1036     0.0784    -0.0529     0.1053    -0.0511    -0.0138 -0.2089  0.1295 -0.0391
```

NOTE: As showed in the example, we assume that the 'dog' column sequence corresponds to the 'cat' column sequence i.e. 1:100

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Z_dog1_mu1 = c(0, 0.0039, -0.038, -0.1036), Z_dog2_mu1 = c(0, 
-0.0016, -0.0733, 0.0784), Z_dog3_mu1 = c(1e-04, -0.0102, 0.0196, 
-0.0529), Z_cat1_mu1 = c(5e-04, -9e-04, 0.0261, 0.1053), Z_cat2_mu1 = c(0.0043, 
0.0421, 0.0628, -0.0511), Z_cat3_mu1 = c(0.0045, -0.0139, 0.0463, 
-0.0138)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: something is not right, it is creating 200 diff columns i am unable to open the dataset it is taking a long time, which is understandable due the large number of columns as is, but 200 diff columns...hmmm....what could have been ?

Comment: @KimJenkins. Can you check the `length(nmdog)` and `length(nmcat)`. If both are the same, it should work fine

Comment: @KimJenkins. Do you have a `matrix` or `data.frame`  or `data.table` or `tbl_df` ?

Comment: my bad, i see that there are 200 columns each , so we are good. Thanks.