# dplyr mutate: pass list of variables to create multiple new variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to do something that intuitively feels straightforward but I can't figure it out. I'm hoping to calculate delta's for a number of columns: I have columns `A1, B1, C1` and `A2, B2, C2` and would like to create columns `A_delta, B_delta, C_delta` by subtracting `A2 - A1` etc.

Here's what I thought I could do with `dplyr` (using `mtcars` as example):

```
# Create test data with changed columns
d.test <- mtcars %>% 
            rownames_to_column() %>% 
            mutate(mpg2 = mpg - 4, 
                   cyl2 = cyl - 1)

# Calculate deltas & add as new columns
d.test %>% mutate(!!c("mpg_delta", "cyl_delta") := c(mpg2, cyl2) - c(mpg, cyl))
```

Clearly it doesn't work like this, but I cannot for the life of me figure out the right syntax. I've been reading up on using `purrr` but that seems applicable when trying to do different actions per row (like here [dplyr mutate using variable columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49311043/dplyr-mutate-using-variable-columns)), not when trying to create multiple new columns...

Any pointers would be great!

Comment: `--->` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52731483/r-multiple-column-subtraction

Comment: @Edward Great solution using base R, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `dplyr` and `purrr` possibility could be:

```
map2_dfr(.x = d.test %>%
          select(mpg2, cyl2),
         .y = d.test %>%
          select(mpg, cyl), 
         ~ .x - .y) %>%
 setNames(c("mpg_delta", "cyl_delta"))

   mpg_delta cyl_delta
       <dbl>     <dbl>
 1        -4        -1
 2        -4        -1
 3        -4        -1
 4        -4        -1
 5        -4        -1
 6        -4        -1
 7        -4        -1
 8        -4        -1
 9        -4        -1
10        -4        -1
```

Answer (score 1):

Or:

```
my_diff <- function(d, newvars, vars1, vars2) {
  cmd <- unlist(pmap(list(newvars, vars1, vars2), ~exprs(!!..1 := !!..2 - !!..3)))
  d %>%
    mutate(!!!cmd)
}
d.test %>%
  my_diff(vars(delta_mpg, delta_cyl), vars(mpg2, cyl2), vars(mpg, cyl))
```